# VS static libs in shared lib with def file: alternative to dllexport?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, shared-libraries, static-libraries, dllexport

I'm building a dll with static libs (all C++) and a Module Definition File (.def) generated from all symbols contained in those static libs (dumpbin.exe /LINKERMEMBERS).

If I build my static libs as is, link it in my dll, some symbols are missing (ie inline functions), so I have to dllexport in the static libs to force the explicit instantiation of symbols, but the export has some unwanted side effects when I staticly compile programs with those static libs (without the dll) (warning 4217 and 4049 which are legitimate, a .exp file and all symbols exported in the .exe program itself).

So, my question is:

Does stackoverlow know a VS2010 (or VS2012) magic attribute or declspec to force the instantiation of a symbol without exporting it (but no noinline) ? or how to remove exports of my static libs (keeping the symbols) ?

PS: I need to use the same static libs for either the dll creation or for simple static linking to gain a lot of compilation time.

EDIT: This is tricky, I hope it will help to help me:

```
               libD.def gen from libS.lib's symbols
                so libD will dllexport Func()
             +----------------------------------+
             |                                  V
+----------------+                            +-------------+
|    libS.lib    |    static link libS.lib    |  libD.dll   |
|                |--------------------------->|( dllexport  |
|dllexport Func()|                            |   Func()  ) |
+----------------+      +-------------+       +-------------+
        |               |   libP.lib  |             |
        | static link   |  dllimport  |             | dyn link
        | libS.lib      |    Func()   |             |
        |               +-------------+             |
        V                |  static   |              V
+----------------+       |   link    |        +-------------+
|     a.exe      |<------+           +------->|   b.exe     |
|                |                            | dllimport   |
|     Func()     |                            |   Func()    |
+----------------+                  dllimport +-------------+
!!- will have exported                Func()        OK
    Func() in the .exe
!!- will warn about
    Func() localy defined
    but imported
```

NOTE: weird things happen: a.exe will export Func() even if "func.h" doesn't dllexport it (I thing because of the dllexport compiled in libS.lib), but I have to explicitly generate a def file to dllexport Func() in libD.dll ...

Comment: IMO not so clear what you're asking for but *usually* dllexport/dllimport are defined through a macro (to reuse same header both in library and its users). It should be VS default for any new library project.

Comment: Yep, I use macros. But I want to use same library (the .lib library) for static link and dynamic link via an intermediate dll that link that static lib. But to correctly generate the .def file for the dll I need to dllexport to create symbols, but that same lib compiled with dllexport is also used as a simple static lib, and here problems appears...

Comment: I mean: use THREE macros to define how everything (dllimport/dllexport/nothing) has to be translated. One for your lib, one for your intermediate lib (BTW how you resolved problems with names?) and one for final users

Comment: I added some details. What name problems ?